# FreeMember - logout tag redirecting to a blank page

Tags: freemember

When attempting to logout using the freemember logout URL tag the page is re-directing to a blank page with the desired url path output: https://www.site-name.com/?ACT=56&return_url=%2F

I have also tried other paths, that is other than redirecting to the home page.

Any ideas?

Comment: Seemi have another FreemMember issue and i wonder if they are related: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/6096/freemember-register-create-account-return-403-error

Answer (score 2):

Blank page usually means there is some PHP or MySQL error, but it is suppressed by EE debugging level. Try setting "Show error to everyone" in Output Preferences and see if you get any message.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `$debug = 1;` in your `index.php` file.

This will force EE to display any PHP errors that might be being hidden on that page.

Alternatively, you might have some crazy htaccess rules which are breaking the `?ACT` URL (this is an EE action URL used by FreeMember, in this case to log out the current user).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the {exp:freemember:logout_url} trying setting return="example/page"

```
{exp:freemember:logout_url return="example/page"}
```

Comment: Also you can view all Freemember documentation here (https://github.com/expressodev/freemember/wiki).

Comment: Other than that suggestion, without seeing your template, config, etc. I don't anyone will be much help.

Comment: here is the tag template in use: {exp:freemember:logout_url return="/"}

With a path other than the "/" is returns the blank page with: https://www.site-name.com/?ACT=56&return_url=example%2Fpage

Comment: What version of EE and Freemember are you using, I tested with EECMS 2.5.5 and Freemember 2.1.1 and had no issues.

Comment: Yes, i am using both 2.5.5 and 2.1.1

Comment: I'm having the same issue with 2.5.5 and 2.1.1. MSM is installed in my case.