# FreeMember register/create account return 403 error

Tags: freemember

When submitting the freemember register and login pages I am getting 403 errors returned. This isn’t happening on any other form/page on the site and the unsubmitted pages themselves load fine. Its just when I submit the form that the 403 is thrown back.

Could it be related to SSL?

Comment: What does the Chrome/Firebug Network tab show? Are there any errors in the JS console? Are you using any other form plugins on this site, and do they work? Which ones?

Comment: Also, in your question a couple days ago you had a different error with the registration form, and no 403 errors. What has changed between now and then?

Comment: I tested the logout tag before the other tags so I assume the 403 issue was already there.

I thought it may have been due to removing Zoo Visitor and then installing FreeMember so I started with a fresh install and rebuilt the whole site. Since then i have applied the htaccess you suggested and enforced SSL, i have also been through the database and site files to make sure there is no SSL mismatch.

Comment: I just tested the FreeMember login page whilst being logged in as a super admin, on submitting an empty form the correct error validation was returned instead of the 403.

Permissions related issue? Been through the member preferences and everything seems correctly set.

Comment: Do you have any template caching or caching plugins enabled? I'm a little confused how you are testing a login form while logged in...

Comment: No template caching or caching plugins. I am using the "members" group which is for customers and on those pages I am testing specifically for that member group - therefore a super admin can see the front end of the site in the same way as a customer. When i attempt to login/create an account without being logged in i get the 403 error. By accident i attempted to log in whilst already being logged in as a super admin in the same browser and thats when the page with error validation was returned instead of the 403 error.

Comment: Hey there - this is the first of two reports of this issue. Can you let me know your EE, Assets, and Freemember versions, please?  Did you ask the Freemember author about this?

Comment: This is the other thread: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/6583/403-error-with-assets-and-freemember

Comment: I'm going to mark this as a duplicate of the other question (even though this was here first), since the other question has much more information about the cause of this. Thanks for your help so far diagnosing this Adam. Watch the other thread for updates :)

Comment: The other thread is updated with the answer and a patch. :)