# 403 Error with Assets 2.0.5 and Freemember

Tags: add-on, assets, freemember

I'm running into an issue with Assets and Freemember running together. I've narrowed it down to some code in Assets.

Freemember is throwing a 403 error on register because it's generating the template from the ACTION function. This is causing Assets to throw a 403 because it's checking for an ACTION request on line 24 of sources/ee/source.ee.php.

Is this something that can be fixed in assets or should Freemember fix it?

This is happening on:
EE 2.5.5
Assets 2.0.5
Freemember 2.1.1

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: Generating the template from an action post request is fairly standard (safecracker does it). So I *think* it's something Assets needs to fix. Lets see what their team has to say about it.

Comment: Hey Chris - can you update your posts with version numbers for Assets and EE, please, as well as Freemember?  Do you see any other issues with registration (using the built-in forms) or with Assets in other parts of your site?  Thanks!

Comment: Also see another person having this issue: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/6096/freemember-register-create-account-return-403-error - also curious if you've asked the Freemember author about it as well?  I'll have to try to reproduce this most likely to see what may be going on.

Comment: Hi Lisa - I've updated the posts with version numbers. That post sounds like a similar issue, but it was never resolved. I was able to fix it, temporarily, by removing the line in Assets that sends a 403 error, so I don't think it's a Freemember issue.

Comment: Hi, Chris - I've actually reported this as a bug to our team.  There's another report on GetSatisfaction with SafeCracker, Assets, and this.  I'll update you once I have more information.

Comment: For the record, we are working with the P&T team to solve this as well. I'm fairly sure it's something which needs to be fixed in Assets though, as the FreeMember form handling works in the exact same way as safecracker (which I believe also triggers this 403 issue).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out that this was, indeed, an issue with Assets.

Andris worked on this overnight and figured out what was going on.  Essentially, Assets thought that if it reached that part of the code and had to submit an ACT request, then Assets would be the one doing the ACTion.  That is not always the case.

This will be fixed Assets 2.1 but that is a bit off.  So, here is the patch with instructions for where to apply the code changes.

http://pastie.org/private/stx2abio8navxese2i4zq

Make sure you back up your files first!