# Clicking 'submit' on FreeMember login form just goes to blank page

Tags: freemember

Well basically like the title says, no errors are generated, I just get a blank page back...

Heres my form:

```
{embed="includes/.sitetop" pagetitle="Gateway Workshops - Massage Courses UK - New member registration" page="register login questionnaire"}
<div class="slidewrap noslide" style="background-color: white;"></div>
<div class="centercolumn">
    <h3>Register New Account</h3>
    {exp:freemember:register require="email|name|phone|password" return="site/thankyou/" error_handling="inline" error_delimiters='<span class="error">|</span>'}
    <p><label for="name">Name:</label> {field:name}<br />{error:name}</p>
    <p><label for="email">Email Address:</label> {field:email}<br />{error:email}</p>
    <p><label for="company">Company Name:</label> {field:company}<br />{error:company}</p>
    <p><label for="job_title">Job Title:</label> {field:job_title}<br />{error:job_title}</p>
    <p><label for="phone">Phone Number:</label> {field:phone}<br />{error:phone}</p>
    <p><label for="address">Address:</label>{field:address}<br />{error:address}</p>
    <p><label for="password">Password:</label> {field:password}<br />{error:password}</p>
    <p><label for="password_confirm">Confirm Password:</label>{field:password_confirm}<br />{error:password_confirm}</p>
{if captcha}
    <p>Please enter the following characters into the box below:<br />
    {captcha}<br />
    {field:captcha}<br />
    {error:captcha}</p>
{/if}

<div class="button"><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit"><div class="buttoninner"><div class="buttoninnerinner">Submit Questionnaire</div></div></div></input>



    {/exp:freemember:register}
</div>
{embed="includes/.sitebottom"}
```

Its fairly simple, nothing too fancy there, it all displays fine on:
/login/register/
but when you click the submit button it goes to:
/index.php/login/register
and displays a blank page.

If I go directly to /index.php/login/register and hit submit it does the same thing (aka redirects back to itself) regardless of what else I do in the form.

I've got PHP errors turned on and am getting no errors appearing for the site, just the form seems to consistently return to a blank page.....

Thanks

Steven Lockey

Comment: Are you running the latest version of FreeMember?

Comment: +1 on updating to latest FreeMember version. Also try renaming/deleting your `.htaccess` then visiting `/index.php/login/register` and try again.

Comment: Downloaded the latest version from Git yesterday.

Comment: Exactly the same thing happens with no .htaccess file as well

Comment: EE is version 2.5.3 if that makes a difference, we have the Expresso Store, Playa, Matrix, TitleMaster and Wygwam modules running as well as the default modules in EE.

Thanks

Comment: It was Assets conflicting, I've put in the fix from Pixel And Tonic now and it seems to be working.

Comment: http://pastie.org/private/stx2abio8navxese2i4zq
is the fix in case anyone else comes across the bug and needs the fix.

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be a conflict with assets ([403 Error with Assets 2.0.5 and Freemember](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/q/6583/150)).

http://pastie.org/private/stx2abio8navxese2i4zq has the fix in case anyone else comes across the bug and needs the fix.